# iPad Refreshes to Old Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, scroll

I am working on a website that must perform well on an iPad according to the requirements. As I scroll vertically, different actions are taken relative to how far we have scrolled. For instance:

```
if( $("div.stack").offset().top-$(window).scrollTop() >= 0 ){
    $("div.main-nav").animate({top:$("div.stack").offset().top}, {duration:350, easing:'easeOutBack'});
}
else if( $("div.stack").offset().top-$(window).scrollTop() < 0 ){
    $("div.main-nav").animate({top:$(window).scrollTop()+50}, {duration:350, easing:'easeOutBack'});
}
```

When I load the site everything works well as I scroll. Lets say I have scrolled halfway down and then hit refresh: the Javascript is fired when the page loads (at the top) THEN it takes you down to the old location.

The result is that all functionality is run with no scroll taken into account THEN it takes you down to the old location. Is there an event for execute-after-the-iPad-takes-me-to-old-location?